# SQL Check for Null Date and then Case Switch

Tags: sql, switch-statement, case

I have a data result that I want to filter by two different dates.

The below is working except when completion_date is null. If it is null I want to use a different field called created_date.

```
string strSQL = string.Format(@"select * from my_table 

            where user_Id = {0}

            AND [completion_date] between {1} AND {2}

            order by completion_status  desc, [completion_date] asc"
            , userId, dateStart, dateEnd, visibilityIndicator);
```

Perhaps something like this:

```
string strSQL = string.Format(@"select * from my_table                                                   
where user_Id = {0}


CASE completion_date 
     WHEN is null THEN [completion_date] between {1} AND {2}
     ELSE [created_date] between {1} AND {2}

END 

AND                       
            order by completion_status  desc, [completion_date] asc"
            , userId, dateStart, dateEnd, visibilityIndicator);
```

What is the best way to check for that null value and then switch to created_date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where isnull(completetion_date,created_date) between {1} and {2}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
string strSQL = string.Format(@"select * from my_table 
where user_Id = {0}
AND ISNULL([completion_date],[created_date]) between {1} AND {2}
 order by completion_status  desc, [completion_date] asc"
```

Answer (score 0):

An ANSI SQL compliant version:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_Id = {0}
AND [completion_date] BETWEEN {1} AND {2}
OR ([completion_date] IS NULL AND [created_date] BETWEEN {1} AND {2})
ORDER BY completion_status DESC, [completion_date] ASC
```

Comment: There is also the ANSI `COALESCE` but not sure if it is applicable here...maybe.

Comment: Thanks! An interesting solution. I try to avoid Coalesce if possible, just as a personal preference.